# How can I constrain generic type arguments of a trait which depend on each other?

Tags: generics, rust, type-constraints

I have a trait for types which process data:

```rust
pub trait Stage<I, O>: Sized {}
```

Here, `I` and `O` represent the input and output data types respectively. I want to create an implementation of `Stage` which combines two other `Stage`s:

```rust
pub struct CompoundStage<S0: Stage<_, _>, S1: Stage<_, _>>(S0, S1);
```

`CompoundStage` must itself be a `Stage`:

```rust
impl<S0: Stage<_, _>, S1: Stage<_, _>> Stage<S0::I, S1::O> for CompoundStage<S0, S1> {}
```

How can I constrain the type arguments of `CompoundStage` such that the “intermediate” type is consistent (i.e. `S0::O == S1::I`)? I know I could do it by adding another type parameter like below, but is there a cleaner way?

```rust
pub struct CompoundStage<S0: Stage<_, T>, S1: Stage<T, _>, T>(S0, S1);

impl<S0: Stage<_, T>, S1: Stage<T, _>, T> Stage<S0::I, S1::O> for CompoundStage<S0, S1, T> {}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. The code you've provided isn't consistent with itself and fails to compile. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You *probably* want a trait with associated types instead of generic types:

```rust
pub trait Stage: Sized {
    type I;
    type O;
}

pub struct CompoundStage<S0, S1>(S0, S1);

impl<S0, S1> Stage for CompoundStage<S0, S1>
where
    S0: Stage,
    S1: Stage<I = S0::O>,
{
    type I = S0::I;
    type O = S1::O;
}
```

See also:

- [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/155423)
- [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/155423)
- [How can I enforce equality of two associated type parameters of traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42378514/155423)
- [Matching a generic parameter to an associated type in an impl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29345708/155423)
- [Constraints on associated trait types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33520049/155423)

---

If you must use generic types, you will need to introduce `PhantomData`:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait Stage<I, O>: Sized {}

pub struct CompoundStage<S0, S1, M>(S0, S1, PhantomData<M>);

impl<S0, S1, I, O, M> Stage<I, O> for CompoundStage<S0, S1, M>
where
    S0: Stage<I, M>,
    S1: Stage<M, O>,
{
}
```